# KeyError when creating new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to open the two most recent .csv files from a folder stored on my hard drive. Upon reading in each df, I want to create a column containing the name of the file that was read in, but I keep getting **KeyError: 'file_name'**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
files = glob.glob(r"path\*.csv")
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=os.path.getmtime, reverse = True) #sorting files from newest to oldest

buyandsell_df = []
for index, file in enumerate(sorted_files):
    if index == 2: #only open two most recent files from sorted_files list
        break
    else:
        print("READING IN " + file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['language','title','contract_number','publishing_status','award_date','publication_date','amendment_date','contract_value'], low_memory = False)
        df['file_name'] = file
        df = df.loc[df['language'] == 'English'] # filter out french duplicates
        buyandsell_df.append(df)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the structure of the `df` object after the `df = pd.read_csv(...)` line?

Comment: The error is that `'file_name'` is not in `df`

Comment: What makes you think `df['file_name']` exists? `df=pd.read_csv...` is producing a data frame not a file.

Comment: Is this the actual code? Which line of code results in KeyError? You should always include full diagnostic information in your post.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver if you are assigning a new key value python dict will create a new one this is not the source of the error. he is probably reading from it before creating it somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should work. It looks for all `.csv` files in `rootdir`.
I used 2 subfolders (`Dir1` and `Dir2`) and in both 2 files (`A.csv`, `B.csv` and `C.csv`, `D.csv`).

Script:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

rootdir = 'RootDir' # Change when needed to your root directory
files = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(rootdir) for f in filenames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.csv']
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)

buyandsell_df = []
for index, file in enumerate(sorted_files):
    if index == 2: #only open two most recent files from sorted_files list
        break
    else:
        print("READING IN " + file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['language','title','contract_number','publishing_status','award_date','publication_date','amendment_date','contract_value'], low_memory = False)
        df['file_name'] = file
        df = df.loc[df['language'] == 'English'] # filter out french duplicates
        buyandsell_df.append(df)
buyandsell_df
```

Output (list of 2 dataframes):

```
READING IN RootDir/Dir2/D.csv
READING IN RootDir/Dir2/C.csv

[  language title  contract_number publishing_status  award_date  \
 0  English     D                4                 Y  2022-07-29   
 
   publication_date amendment_date  contract_value           file_name  
 0       2022-07-29     2022-07-29              10  RootDir/Dir2/D.csv  ,
   language title  contract_number publishing_status  award_date  \
 0  English     C                3                 Y  2022-07-29   
 
   publication_date amendment_date  contract_value           file_name  
 0       2022-07-29     2022-07-29              10  RootDir/Dir2/C.csv  ]
```

As an alternative, you can use a `dict` by changing `buyandsell_df = []` to `buyandsell_df = {}` and `buyandsell_df.append(df)` to `buyandsell[file] = df` and remove `df['file_name'] = file`. This prevents copying the file name to all rows for all dataframes. File names are stored as dictionary keys.

Comment: Yes, it should work. But the posted code is almost certainly not the code that the OP is actually running.